# OctoberCMS Image returns json

Tags: octobercms

I am trying to show an image uploaded on the backend, however when I use it in the src attribute, it returns a json string. What is weird, is that I do use the same method earlier in the page and it works there. It doesn't work here:

```
<img src="{{ associate.banner }}">
```

It outputs

```
<img src="{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;disk_name&quot;:&quot;54a7d97d49a03640202890.png&quot;,&quot;file_name&quot;:&quot;buycraftlogo.png&quot;,&quot;file_size&quot;:7146,&quot;content_type&quot;:&quot;image\/png&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:null,&quot;description&quot;:null,&quot;field&quot;:&quot;banner&quot;,&quot;sort_order&quot;:1,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2015-01-03 11:58:53&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2015-01-03 11:59:12&quot;,&quot;path&quot;:&quot;\/uploads\/public\/54a\/7d9\/7d4\/54a7d97d49a03640202890.png&quot;,&quot;extension&quot;:&quot;png&quot;}">
```

Here it does work:

```
{% set img = member.profile_img %}
<img src="{{ img }}" class="responsive-img">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where you have placed code for image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload the image file (or every file) to the October, It saves in the `uploads` directory and create a file model in the `system_files` table.

If you retrieve the file from the database, it will return the `File` object, not the file path. Hence, you will see the JSON of `File` object in the `src` attribute.

However, you can get the path from it via `path` property.

```
<img src="{{ associate.banner.path }}">
```

And the result should be

```
<img src="/uploads/public/54a/7d9/7d4/54a7d97d49a03640202890.png">
```